# Error on binding Select DropDown using JSON Result from Data Base

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

```
<select id="DdlModule" class="form-control input-sm "> </select>
```

**Jquery Code to BInd Ddl Module**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "/Job/GetModules",
    data: "{}",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (Result) {
            $("#DdlModule").append("<option value='0'>---Select---</option>");
            $.each(Result.d, function (key, value) {
                $("#ddlmodule").append($("<option></option>").val(value.modId).html(value.modName));
            });
    },
    error: function (Result) {
        alert("Error");
    }
});
```

**Here is my Controller Action**

```
public JsonResult GetModules()
{
    var Query = "EXEC [dbo].[Usp_ComboBind] @TableName='Module'";
    List<Usp_ComboBind_Module> objModule = objDbContext.Database.SqlQuery<Usp_ComboBind_Module>(Query).ToList();
    return Json(objModule, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**Error**

> Error:jquery-1.10.2.min.js:21 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: Not related, but delete the pointless `contentType` and `data` attributes, and there is no need for `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` if your making a POST

Comment: ok.thank you ,But Error is not solved yet

Comment: Use `$.each(Result, function (key, value) {` (not `Result.d`)

Comment: thank you code works after changed to Result Instead of Result.d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using `type: "POST"` in AJAX callback, make sure that `HttpPostAttribute` attribute included in controller action method like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetModules()
{
    var Query = "EXEC [dbo].[Usp_ComboBind] @TableName='Module'";
    List<Usp_ComboBind_Module> objModule = objDbContext.Database.SqlQuery<Usp_ComboBind_Module>(Query).ToList();
    return Json(objModule);
}
```

And then put a check against `undefined` inside `success` result before iterating `Result` function parameter:

```
success: function (Result) {
    if (typeof Result !== 'undefined' && Result != undefined) {
        $("#DdlModule").append("<option value='0'>---Select---</option>");
        $.each(Result, function (key, value) {
            $("#ddlmodule").append($("<option></option>").val(value.modId).html(value.modName));
        });
    }
},
```

**Note:** *Cannot read property 'length' of undefined* occurs because you're trying to iterate an object which has `undefined` value, since `$.each` expects an array or collection object.